# Suggestion - Possibly Sitewide - Inbox Feed?

Tags: feature-request, rss

I might be being dense, but I was wondering if there is a RSS feed that displays entries from our 'inbox'? If not, then perhaps a feature suggestion.

I use a RSS reader a lot and it updates constantly in the background - I just thought it'd be cool.

Answer (score 2):

I have just added this capability to my website. You can read all of the details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135045/142114).

Basically the process goes something like this:

1. Register for an account on my website.
2. Connect your new account to your Stack Exchange profile.
3. Authorize my website to access your inbox.
4. Receive a custom RSS feed URL that contains the contents of your inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan is correct. For a close approximation, though, try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/15589/responses

(substitute your own user number for best results; this one is for the OP)

Comment: Oh Safari and your 'feed://' "protocol" handler :/.

Comment: Sorry, @JasonSalaz I copied and pasted without checking the protocol.

Comment: @JasonSalaz Edited

Comment: This seems to be "responses *from* so-and-so," rather than "responses *to* so-and-so."

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this feature isn't available.

[It's been asked for before, actually.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85897/is-there-a-rss-to-the-stackexchange-inbox-how-about-to-activity)

The solution, according to answers to the above post, is that you would have to convert the JSON to RSS yourself. Not hard, but not exactly automatic.