# How difficult would it be to make an RSS feed of notifications?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, rss, inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestion - Possibly Sitewide - Inbox Feed?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/971/suggestion-possibly-sitewide-inbox-feed)

I'm picturing an RSS feed for each user which would contain notifications from the Inbox. This way, I could get an instant notification via Boxcar or ifttt and wouldn't find out three hours later.

An alternative would be to send the emails immediately, but only if the user is not currently on the site.